# How to create Mac OS X dev environment for legacy PHP app?

Tags: php, macos, xampp, development-environment

I've just been assigned to start working with the code from a large, legacy PHP app. A copy is running on the production servers, and I've pulled a copy from the code repositories onto my local machine.

I installed XAMPP in hopes of running the app locally during development, but I'm stuck. How do I (1) get XAMPP to point to my development folder and (2) actually get the PHP app up and running locally (including database tables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Move your development folder into the htdocs folder where ever you installed XAMPP to ie: C:\xampp\htdocs\my_legacy_php_app\ and then browse to http://localhost/my_legacy_php_app/ to see it in action.
2) You would need to migrate the database to your test environment, most people find using phpMyAdmin pretty easy, so, navigate to http://localhost/phpMyAdmin and import the database.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use the MacOSX default installation of the web server and PHP. To run the web server, you just click on Web sharing on system preferences. To activate PHP 5.x, edit the `httpd.conf` file in the `/private/etc/apache2 directory`.

Then download MySql DMG version and install it as a usual Mac application. You can start MySql using command `mysql -u user -p password`
You may then transfer the whole directory to your home/Sites folder.

I prefer using default installation because it allows me to install pear packages easier than if I use XAMPP.