# Running PHP file outside of documentroot (cgi-bin folder)

Tags: php, xampp, virtualhost, cgi-bin

I am working with a colleague to set up their local environment on a MAC in XAMPP, on windows my vhost looks like the one below.

When I access a URL like http://domain.local/cgi-bin/handler.php the web server processes the PHP correctly but on his we get a 500 server error and this message...

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
Premature end of script headers:
```

We tried changing the name of the cgi-bin folder to something else as I noticed there was another alias in httpd.conf but this had no effect...so it seems to me like the issue is permissions related.

We believe the alias is setup ok as accessing http://domain.local/cgi-bin/filenothere.php which doesn't exist throws a 404 as expected, any .html/.pl files fail to execute.

The permissions that exist on the cgi-bin folder are...

rwxrwxrwx    dave    staff

and is owned by the user and group....

dave staff

Vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  www.domain.local
    ServerAlias domain.local
ServerAlias api.domain.local

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot E:/home/www/www.domain.co.uk/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ E:/home/www/www.domain.co.uk/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>

    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  E:/home/www/www.domain.co.uk/logs/error.log
    CustomLog E:/home/www/www.domain.co.uk/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea what is causing this PHP file to not be executed?

**UPDATE**
Tried adding a header to say that the content is PHP to the start of the PHP file and this now simply outputs the PHP code.

It's as if any path specified in as an Alias is accessible but the server doesn't know how to execute the content, this is for HTML as well as PHP

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with handler.php? What are the permissions on that file?

Comment: The permissions were set recursively for the whole folder in an attempt to get this working.

I've updated question with some extra information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, will look at them today and try and assign this bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a  section for your cgi-bin.

The fact that your server can show you the script sources means the server has at least read permissions on /file/system/path/to/cgi-bin and IIRC that clashes with ScriptAlias b/c ScriptAlias expects /file/system/path/to/cgi-bin to be unaccessible for security reasons. I think your solution should look something along the lines of:

```
<Directory /file/system/path/to/cgi-bin>
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory
```

Comment: Just checked: the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) seems to agree with my answer. At least it proposes about the same config-directives ...

Comment: Thanks this appeared to help with the issue we had, I did however change the sethandler value to the one suggested by @A. R. Younce so I updated voted his answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is (very) rarely a need to run PHP scripts as CGIs given that the PHP module for Apache can execute them directly. Try adding this to your Apache config:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Afterwards simply place the PHP scripts into the document root for the site and see if they work. You'll want to **remove the /cgi-bin/ part of the URL**.

You say you're setting XAMMP on a Mac, but you have a drive letter (E:) prefixing your paths. OS X does not have drive letters like Windows, and this may also be causing (part of) your issue.

Comment: I believe the benefit is you can execute PHP as a different user e.g. have a different user per virtual host, which cannot be done if apache is running php itself via built-in module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about settings used. But I think you should go through following links. Might get some help.

1. http://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2009/02/setting-up-a-phpmysql-local-development-environment-on-a-mac-doing-it-properly/
2. http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/using-joomla/setting-up-a-quick-start-package-on-your-local-server-xampp-pc
3. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html
4. [How to create Mac OS X dev environment for legacy PHP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731355/how-to-create-mac-os-x-dev-environment-for-legacy-php-app)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PHP is running in Safe Mode you may need to "open" your `cgi-bin` directory, as the execution of user (PHP) scripts is limited to the DocumentRoot and it's subfolders.

For all I know you could do that in two ways

**1. Edit your `php.ini`**

Locate the line containing `open_basedir`. If there's a comment at the beginning of the line - a semicolon - remove it. Then add your `cgi-bin` directory.

`open_basedir = "E:\home\www\www.domain.co.uk\cgi-bin\"`

If you need to open more than one directories you can use semicolon `;` as a separator. On Linux based server, use a colon `:`

`open_basedir = "E:\home\www\www.domain.co.uk\cgi-bin\;E:\home\www\www.domain.co.uk\another_dir\"`

In cases like mine, where your server is hosted by third party, you'd need the second option (well sort of)

**2. Edit your VirtualHost**

Add the following to your VirtualHost, i.e. after `DocumentRoot`:

`php_admin_value open_basedir "E:\home\www\www.domain.co.uk\cgi-bin\"`

Same rules apply here for multiple directories and difference between Linux and Windows systems as above.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for response, unfortunately a combination of first two answers fixed issue so I didn't get to try the above...I had a look in the PHP manual and I can imagine that something like this would also have a good chance of fixing this issue too.

Comment: It's important you've solved your problem :) This can be considered for cases where SafeMode is On (which is preferable) and you'd like to run php scripts from other directories, different than DocumentRoot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know whether PHP is running as a CGI program or as a webserver module? You should be able to find this out if you can get a phpinfo() page working (maybe from a regular folder inside the website root). If you're running as a webserver module then you should have a section near the top with a heading of `Server API` which says `Apache 2.0 Handler` (or equivalent).

From these pages:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13316
- http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php
- http://gallery.menalto.com/node/8955

... it seems that it may be either due to PHP running as a CGI script, or else a conflict between PHP and another CGI handler.

One of the posters on the third linked page found that their similar-sounding `end of script headers` issue was resolved by removing / commenting out the `Options +ExecCGI` line in their .htconfig / vhosts file.

Might be worth having a read through the above links to see if your problem is related.