# Using PHP scripts from html on mac's default web server

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm developing a site with `PHP` and I need to test it using my Web Server on Mac. I installed the server and made sure it's working. Localhost is seeing and serving whatever I put in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.

Now I put a test script in the `CGI-Executables` directory, and tried calling it from an `html` file inside the `Documents` directory. It results in this error:

```
The requested URL /CGI-Executables/SM.php was not found on this server.
```

The file is there, so I'm assuming it's a configuration issue, and looking around I played with the `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file but it seems like an overkill. I don't need a virtual host, and I'm not going to serve anything from my development machine. I just want to develop my site.

Comment: what is the location of your CGI-Executables folder? Also, I would suggest keeping the names to all lower case to keep things simpler. Can you access http://localhost/CGI-Executables/ ?

Comment: If you wanted a simple work around could you not just reference the folder relatively like ../../CGI-Executables? I know this wont fix your config issue though

Comment: @AnshuPrateek, my CGI-Executables is in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables. The name was there and is probably the default, not something I created. When I'm hitting localhost/CGIExecutables/SM.php I'm getting a "The requested URL /CGI-Executables/SM.php was not found on this server" error. (the file is there.)

Comment: @JammyDodger231 it doesn't work.

Comment: You should either put your scripts in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ or call them like /cgi-bin/SM.php

Answer (score 0):

You should either put your scripts in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ or call them like /cgi-bin/SM.php  Also, are you sure you want cgi scripts or do you just need your php to work? If its the latter, then putting them up in the Document root is a better option than using it as cgi script.

Comment: I don't think I should put them in the Documents folder. These are server files and should be served from the cgi-bin directory, isn't it? I tried the name variations you suggest but they're 'not found'.

Comment: what are you trying to do in your php file? All files on server are "server files". Docroot is not meant only for html files. Do you need a html file in the first place? anyways, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411272/running-php-file-outside-of-documentroot-cgi-bin-folder